# How to find Indy servers in Delphi7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

Can't find INDY SERVERS in my Delpi7 how to fix this I need to work with winsocks but I can't find it on panel of delphi7 ide

Comment: In download section there's only indy10, indy9, indy8, winshoes 7 and winshoes 6. Or winshoes 7 is the same thing?

Comment: @fantaghirocco: every version of Delphi has shipped with Indy preinstalled going back to at least Delphi 6.  I can confirm that Delphi 7 did ship with Indy (8 or 9, I forget which, but definitely not 10).  And BTW, your download link is old, the correct link is http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/wizard/DownloadWizard.aspx

Comment: @JAXPAROW95: Winshoes is the predecessor to Indy.  The latest Indy is Indy 10, which can be used in Delphi 7.  Stay away from Winshoes, and Indy 8.  Use Indy 9 at a minimum, but Indy 10 is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a standard Delphi7 install, try this

- In the IDE go to `Component | Install packages`
- In the pop-up, click `Add` and navigate to your Delphi Bin folder, you should see a package dclIndy70.Bpl.  `Open` it.

You should now have the Indy components on your Component Palette.  They'll be a bit out of date, of course, as Indy has moved on a bit since their time.

Btw, if you decide to upgrade to a more recent version of Indy, make sure you make a back up of your entire project, especially the .DFM(s).  With such a long time between the version which was current for D7 and now, you may find that some component properties are now out of date, so the IDE will complain when loading the .DFM(s).

Comment: There is only indy7.map in the component | install packages @MartynA

Comment: Then your install is faulty - it's on the Delphi 7 install CD (I just checked) so you can copy it from there.

Comment: Sure my cd must be fault I have no alternative

Comment: Then either download a current version of Indy, or see if you can find an online archived version from the D7 era (2002?)  Or google "dclindy70.bpl download"